# Bundled Product but without giving options to customer

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, bundled-product, bundle

I am wanting to create a product that is made up of a fixed number of other, already existing, products, eg. Tableware Set, containing 4 plates, 2 serving plates, 4 knives, 4 forks and 1 salad bowl.

The customer should not be able to change the quantities within the set. You could buy 1,2,3 etc Tableware Sets but you can't mess with the set itself.

I have created a "Bundled Product", and tried a "Grouped Product" too, but Magento always seems to allow the customer to play with the quantities within the set and even exclude items completely.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong and how I can provide a fixed bundle that consequently has a fixed price?

Comment: Addition to the answer in the linked duplicate to address the fixed qty: set "user defined qty" = "no"

Answer (score 0):

Hide the dropdowns with css and set the bundle configuration you want selected by default via the admin panel.

Identify the bundle configuration you wish to set by default.

Locate the corresponding dropdowns you wish to hide, and target with css, for example:

```
#bundle-option-4 {
display:none
}
```

then in Catalog > Manage Products > Bundle Items

[image: Set Bundle Item Default Configuration]

1. Set the Default Qty for each bundled sku
2. Set User Defined Qty to **No**
3. Select Default
4. Save

Comment: Any hints as to how to track down that line of CSS, as suggested?

Comment: If you are viewing the page in Chrome, you can right click on the dropdown and you should get an option for inspect element. From there it should highlight the code rendering the dropdown. Look for id="bundle-option-", then add the appropriate css rule based on my instructions.